# Пустой клик

Tags: jquery

Я новичок, подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка.

Кликаем на любой пункт, потом на другой и закрываем его. Теперь при клике на первый пункт получается пустой клик, т.е. нам нужно дважды кликнуть, что снова открыть меню.

http://jsfiddle.net/siretsky/rrph0uff/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

     $('#TopHmenuService a.TopIndexHref').toggle(
         function() {
             $('#TopHmenuServiceBl').slideDown(600);
             $('#TopHmenuShopBl').slideUp(200);
             return false;
         },
         function() {
             $('#TopHmenuServiceBl').css('display', 'none');
             return true;
         }
     );

     $('#TopHmenuShop a.TopIndexHref').toggle(
         function() {
             $('#TopHmenuShopBl').slideDown(600);
             $('#TopHmenuServiceBl').slideUp(200);
             return false;
         },
         function() {
             $('#TopHmenuShopBl').css('display', 'none');
             return true;
         }
     );

 });
```

Comment: @siretsky, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 7):

Много лишнего. [Всё гораздо проще](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/rrph0uff/4/).

```
$(function(){
    var toggleLink = $('.TopIndexHref');
    toggleLink.click(function(){
        // сворачиваем все блоки, кроме текущего
        toggleLink.not(this).siblings('.MenuCont').slideUp(300);
        // текущий раскрываем, если был свёрнут
        // или сворачиваем в ином случае
        $(this).siblings('.MenuCont').slideToggle(300);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: так слегка универсальнее http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/rrph0uff/6/